# Django: Get User first_name

Tags: python, django, django-models

I can't figure out how to return the string representation of the `User` object's `first_name` and `last_name` fields.
The `User` is built into Django's `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`. 
I want a table `UserDetails` containing extra info on the user so I want the Django admin to display the name of the user the details belong to.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.User.first_name) + ' ' + str(self.User.last_name)
```

This is what I did but it is being presented as:

[image]

I've tried changing model representations in Django admin before. User seems to behave differently though.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `User` it should be model's field name, e.g. if your field named `user` you can do this:

```
class SomeData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name
```

Comment: Also: `return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)`